# Error: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm making a Login form using JSP + JDBC + Servlet.

Whenever I tried to login a username a username and password, I get this error:

SQLState: S1009
Error Code: 0
Message: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

```
public class LoginDao {

    public boolean validate(LoginBean loginBean) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        boolean status = false;

        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myshop?user=root", "root", "12301230");

            // Step 2:Create a statement using connection object
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from myshop.userlogin WHERE username = '?' and password = '?' ")) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, loginBean.getUsername());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, loginBean.getPassword());

            System.out.println(preparedStatement);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            status = rs.next();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // process sql exception
            printSQLException(e);
        }
        return status;
    }

    private void printSQLException(SQLException ex) {
        for (Throwable e: ex) {
            if (e instanceof SQLException) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                System.err.println("SQLState: " + ((SQLException) e).getSQLState());
                System.err.println("Error Code: " + ((SQLException) e).getErrorCode());
                System.err.println("Message: " + e.getMessage());
                Throwable t = ex.getCause();
                while (t != null) {
                    System.out.println("Cause: " + t);
                    t = t.getCause();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I actually haven't tried that much other than restarting my database and creating a new table. I'm actually new to this language and I only got this source code on a tutorial.

Comment: Your statement doesn't have parameters, it has string literals containing question marks.

Comment: The parameter index in SQL queries is counting from 1. The error is not related to JSP.

Answer (score 3):

JDBC will take care of quotes in the query

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
  connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from myshop.userlogin WHERE username = ? and password = ? ")) {
```

Comment: I got this error after removing the quotes.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: SELECT * from myshop.userlogin WHERE username = ** BYTE ARRAY DATA ** and password = ** BYTE ARRAY DATA **

Comment: Different issue. It _looks_ like youre passing a byte array into the query. Post a [mcve]